# groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: configClass for class: java.lang.String

Tags: grails, grails-2.1

I am trying to run my grails project using **grails run-app** command, but the following error has occured:

```
2013-06-05 17:01:49,409 [pool-6-thread-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: configClass for class:   java.lang.String
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.ScriptBytecodeAdapter.unwrap(ScriptBytecodeAdapter.java:50)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.getProperty(PojoMetaClassGetPropertySite.java:35)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetProperty(AbstractCallSite.java:227)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callGetPropertySafe(AbstractCallSite.java:333)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.hibernate.HibernatePluginSupport$__clinit__closure14.doCall(HibernatePluginSupport.groovy:153)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite$PogoCachedMethodSite.invoke(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:226)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.PogoMetaMethodSite.callCurrent(PogoMetaMethodSite.java:52)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.CallSiteArray.defaultCallCurrent(CallSiteArray.java:46)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:133)
at org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.callsite.AbstractCallSite.callCurrent(AbstractCallSite.java:141)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.hibernate.HibernatePluginSupport$__clinit__closure14.doCall(HibernatePluginSupport.groovy)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:601)
at com.springsource.loaded.ri.ReflectiveInterceptor.jlrMethodInvoke(ReflectiveInterceptor.java:1231)
at org.codehaus.groovy.reflection.CachedMethod.invoke(CachedMethod.java:90)
at groovy.lang.MetaMethod.doMethodInvoke(MetaMethod.java:233)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:1047)
at groovy.lang.ExpandoMetaClass.invokeMethod(ExpandoMetaClass.java:1110)
at groovy.lang.MetaClassImpl.invokeMethod(MetaClassImpl.java:877)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:412)
at groovy.lang.Closure.call(Closure.java:406)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:736)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:569)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:511)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.DefaultGrailsPlugin.doWithRuntimeConfiguration(DefaultGrailsPlugin.java:528)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.AbstractGrailsPluginManager.doRuntimeConfiguration(AbstractGrailsPluginManager.java:120)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:156)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.commons.spring.GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.configure(GrailsRuntimeConfigurator.java:127)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsConfigUtils.configureWebApplicationContext(GrailsConfigUtils.java:121)
at org.codehaus.groovy.grails.web.context.GrailsContextLoader.initWebApplicationContext(GrailsContextLoader.java:104)
at org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener.contextInitialized(ContextLoaderListener.java:111)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.listenerStart(StandardContext.java:4779)
at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5273)
at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1566)
at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1556)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
2013-06-05 17:01:49,436 [pool-6-thread-1] ERROR StackTrace  - Full Stack Trace:
groovy.lang.MissingPropertyException: No such property: configClass for class: java.lang.String
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeBeanDefiningClosure(BeanBuilder.java:736)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.beans(BeanBuilder.java:569)
at grails.spring.BeanBuilder.invokeMethod(BeanBuilder.java:511)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask$Sync.innerRun(FutureTask.java:334)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:166)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

I have tried to resolve the issue as mentioned below:

- tried **grails clean**
- removed **GROOVY_HOME** (as grails provide the groovy itself, and i'm running the application from command line)
- cleaned the %USER_HOME%.grails directory manually

But none of the above method solved the issue.

**java -version** returned the following:

```
java version "1.7.0_21"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_21-b11)
Java HotSpot(TM) Client VM (build 23.21-b01, mixed mode, sharing)
```

**grails -version** returned the following:

```
Grails version: 2.1.0
```

New stacktrace log:

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Show the code line with configClass. Maybe you mean metaClass?

Comment: The line containing the configClass is really huge (1331986 characters). I'v found it here: <project-dir>\web-app\js\ext-4.1.3\ext-all-dev.js and ext-all.js.

Comment: Bootstrap code, plz. js are client libs and can't be the reason. The problem in one of the plugins

Comment: I'm working in a organisation, and i don't have permission to share this info. I'm really sorry about that. But I haven't find any string "configClass" there. Is there any other ways?

Comment: I have updated the original questions with the new stacktrace log. It says something about "org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins.orm.hibernate.HibernatePluginSupport$__clinit__closure14.doCall(HibernatePluginSupport.groovy:153)"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Changing the workspace resolved the problem. Just created a new workspace. That's all !!!!

Comment: Sorry, but what do you mean about workspace?

Answer (score 1):

try searching for "configClass" string in your whole project and see what it is, then try commenting it out and see what happens? the error mentions "bootstraps" - maybe it's there?

Comment: I'v got total 8 matches in two files: web-app\js\ext-4.1.3\ext-all-dev.js and ext-all.js. I'v got a new stacktrace result and attaching it to the original question.

Answer (score 0):

Check your `config/DataSource.groovy` for `configClass` and any badly formatted code such as unbalanced quotes. The datasource block sometimes has a block using `configClass` such as the one shown in the [Hibernate Filter plugin documentation](http://grails.org/plugin/hibernate-filter):

```
dataSource {
    …
    configClass = HibernateFilterDomainConfiguration
}
```

Alternatively, perhaps you need to add a `configClass` definition for a plugin to work.